# I made a skin with a second layer and it shows in the picture but not in the game. How do I fix this?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]

The skin I made has two layers, the base and the outer. But whenever I try to login the game, it only shows the base. The download I have clearly has the second layer but why won't it load?

The download picture:

[image: download picture]

This is the skin that shows up:

[image: the skin that shows up]

Answer (score 1):

Turn on your cosmetic armor under **Options > Skin Customization...**

[image]

It sometimes does not sync properly and defaults to off.

Comment: Ah! It did default to off, switched it back and it works! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

first of all, if you have any mods/texture packs applied it might be the cause.
if you have a cracked version that might be the reason